# Using personal SurfaceView on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, surfaceview, double-buffering, setcontentview

I'm currently developing an Android App, using a personal `SurfaceView` and double buffering. However I'm facing a little problem with my code.
In one hand I have an xml view, based on `LinearLayout` hierarchy. When I instantiate my activity, I set my `contentView` on this xml. The problem is then that my double buffering don't works anymore. Thread is running but nothing is displayed.
In the other hand, I set my `contentView` with a new personal `SurfaveView` element and display works fine. But of course, I cannot access anymore to the other elements of my `LinearLayout`.

Actually, I would like to set my `contentView` on my xml view **AND** keep my display working.

I hope I was clear enough, thank you for your answers!

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainController extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle p_savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_controller_activity);

        this.drawableView = (MCustomDrawableView) findViewById(R.id.drawingBox);

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My surface view:

```
public class MCustomDrawableView extends SurfaceView {
    public MCustomDrawableView(Context p_context, AttributeSet p_attributes) {
        super(p_context, p_attributes);

        this.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder p_holder) {
                try {
                    // Instantiating a new thread
                    thread = new MBufferingThread(getInstance());

                    thread.start();

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder p_holder, int p_format, int p_width, int p_height) {...}

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder p_holder) {...}
        });

        // Setup drawing options
        setupDrawing();
    }
    ...
}
```

And my xml view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    tools:context=".MainController">

    <com.iskn.calligraphy.models.draw.MCustomDrawableView
        android:id="@+id/drawingBox"
        style="@style/DrawingBox" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/brushSize"
        style="@style/SizeSeekBar" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/brushOpacity"
        style="@style/OpacitySeekBar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
After further researches and analyses, it appears clearly that:

- `setContentView(R.layout.main_controller_activity)`: in this case I get all the elements from my activity, but the `MCustomDrawableView` display nothing.
- `setContentView(new MCustomDrawableView(getApplicationContext()))`: on that case, `MCustomDrawableView` is working well (it displays what I want), but I don't have the others `View` from my `main_controller_activity`

In both cases:

- my thread is running and works well.
- my drawing function is called as well, with the `holder.lockCanvas()` and `holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(bufferCanvas)` methods.

Comment: What is a "personal" SurfaceView?  SurfaceView is already double- or triple-buffered, why are you adding more buffering?  If the problem is with the buffering or the drawing, you should show that code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I called "personal" SurfaceView is just my MCustomDrawableView class, which extends SurfaceView. In my case, double buffering allows me to perform drawing action on buffered canvas. Then, I post this canvas on displayed one (main). Actually this part works well, my only problem is the link between my main activity, and this class which extends SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a functionnal solution :

I think the problem was coming from the `MCustomDrawableView` initialization . I created a new instance of that class from the `onCreate` method , and not from the xml file . Then, I set it to the `contentView`:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle p_savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_controller_activity);

        // Instantiate drawable object & set style properties
        this.drawableView = new MCustomDrawableView(getApplicationContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams style = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // Add the drawable view to the main_activity
        addContentView(this.drawableView, style);
    }
```

But this way raises a new problem. The added view is on the top, which means that all the others `View` are hided. I solved this with `bringToBack(this.drawableView)` below method:

```
private void bringToBack(View p_view) {
    // Get parent from the current view
    ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup) p_view.getParent());

    int childrenCount = viewGroup.indexOfChild(p_view);
    for(int cpt = 0; cpt < childrenCount; cpt++) {
        // Move the child to the top
        viewGroup.bringChildToFront(viewGroup.getChildAt(cpt));
    }
}
```

It brings back the provided view to the background position. I also had to set the LinearLayout's alpha to 0.

I'm still open to other solutions!